# Javascript EntityFramework Index Table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using ASP.Net Core and used EntityFramework to generate a controller with views. I am working on reworking the Index view where it is dynamic with dropdown selections. I have everything working except there are errors within my JavaScript function.

I will just show the part with the error. It occurs on the s+= line and the error is an unexpected identifier. Does anyone know the cause of this error? The goal is to return the whole line with result[i].name and result[i].value replaced with what I am receiving from my controller.

```
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            s += '<tr><td>'result[i].name'</td><td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="'result[i].value'">Edit</a>| <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="'result[i].value'">Details</a> |<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="'result[i].value'">Delete</a></td></tr>';
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u are missing a `+` operator to concatenate the different strings.

```
s += '<tr><td>' + result[i].name + '</td><td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="' + result[i].value + '">Edit</a>| <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="' + result[i].value + '">Details</a> |<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="' + result[i].value + '">Delete</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. I literally just caught this at the same time you posted this. Can't believe I forgot it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the + between each break. It should be this.

```
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            s += '<tr><td>' + result[i].name + '</td><td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="' + result[i].value + '">Edit</a>| <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="' + result[i].value + '">Details</a> |<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="' + result[i].value + '">Delete</a></td></tr>';
                        }
```